# How to convert 3 times int in MYSQL datareader?

Tags: c#, mysql, converters

How can I convert BestellingAantal ToString because I get an error whats says cannot convert type `string` to `bool` even I made it a int? It is for a loginsystem with C#

```
 String strSQL;
        strSQL =
          "SELECT BestellingId, BestellingProductId, BestellingAantal " +
          "FROM bestellingen";
        oCommand = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, oConnection);
        oDataReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
        //De gegevens staan per record/rij in object DataReader

        //Controleer of er data bestaat alvorens verder te gaan
        if (oDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            //lees rij per rij uit DataReader object
            //oDataReader.Read krijgt de waarde False,
            // indien er geen record meer is 
            while (oDataReader.Read())
            {
                int BestellingId = (int)oDataReader["BestellingId"];
                int BestellingProductId = (int)oDataReader["BestellingProductId"];
                int BestellingAantal = (int)oDataReader["BestellingAantal"];
                Bestelling oBestelling = new Bestelling();
                oBestelling.BestellingId = BestellingId.ToString();
                oBestelling.BestellingProductId = BestellingProductId.ToString();
                oBestelling.BestellingAantal = BestellingAantal.ToString();
                BestellingLijst.Add(oBestelling);
            }
        }
        oConnection.Close();

        if (huidigeGebruiker.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth))
        {
            String Email = String.Parse(huidigeGebruiker.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.).Value);
        }
        return BestellingLijst;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], including the source code of `Bestelling`. Please also include the `CREATE TABLE` script for the database table.

Comment: Thank you! Found the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Are you averse to using Dapper? It's a great micro ORM that lets you carry on writing SQL, but do away with all this tedious crap of reading and casting things with datareaders, opening and closing conenctions etc.. you just write an SQL that maps to an object in your c# and get dapper to run the SQL and build a (list of) objects for you.. Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using Dapper;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Security.Permissions;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string _connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Bestellingen;Uid=root;Pwd=pwd;";

        var service = new BestellingenService(_connectionString);
        var result = service.GetBestellingens();
        foreach(var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.BestellingId);
        }
    }
}

//a class that represents the rows in your db table
public class Bestellingen
{
    public int BestellingId { get; set; }
    public int BestellingProductId { get; set; }
    public int BestellingAantal  { get; set; }
}

//a service that runs SQLs and returns you (lists of) your data mapping class
public class BestellingenService
{
    private readonly MySqlConnection _conn;

    public BestellingenService(string connStr)
    {
        _conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Bestellingen> GetBestellingens()
    {
        var sql = "SELECT BestellingId, BestellingProductId, BestellingAantal FROM bestellingen";
        var result = this._conn.Query<Bestellingen>(sql).ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public Bestellingen GetBestellingenById(int bid)
    {
        var sql = "SELECT BestellingId, BestellingProductId, BestellingAantal FROM bestellingen WHERE id = @pBestellingId";
        var result = this._conn.Query<Bestellingen>(sql, new { pBestellingId = bid }).FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
}
```